# Using TensorFlow Estimator in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have implemented a custom estimator and now I like to use this estimator for training in a loop as follows:

```
for _ in xrange(steps):
   tf.estimator.train(training_iteration)
   post_process_results(...)
```

The problem is that each time tf.estimator.train is being called in the loop a new MonitoredSession is created and never being closed. As such, the allocated memory is never being released and at some point the whole process gets killed because of out of memory exception. Is there anyway to forcefully close the session being created by tf.estimator.train?

Comment: Not sure if you can force close the session, but why would you want to loop over it? the point of the `Estimator` API is you to focus on the `model_fn` and not the training loop.  Can you elaborate more one what you are trying to do, perhaps this example of a [custom estimator](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) would help

Comment: The reason for iteration is to prepare a new batch of training data and then continue training. I use the trained model to generate a new batch of training data 
 (on-policy RL). Another solution is to feed data dynamically in session hooks: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13148

Comment: Just spit balling here, so I may very well be wrong, but you might be able to do this in the `input_fn` (although this might not be most efficient). If you write your newly generated data to TF Records in the training part of your `model_fn` you can in your `input_fn` make your dataset from TF Records using a placeholder for the filenames... but that also seems like a stretch... Alternatively... you could try to embed you new data in variable feature length arrays and update the data that way?